# How configure netrw to use 'l' instead <CR> to open files?

Tags: netrw

By default, netrw uses `l` to move the cursor one letter to the right in the file name.
How can I configure netrw to use the letter `l` to open the file instead of `<CR>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim`:

```
nmap <buffer> l <CR>
```

Or you can use autocommand with filetype event:

```
augroup netrw_setup | au!
    au FileType netrw nmap <buffer> l <CR>
augroup END
```

PS

I also have `h` mapped to `-` giving me nice `l` to open directory, `h` to go to parent directory.

https://github.com/habamax/.vim/blob/59d2782ef41a56a72e6da0d980680d94118aebba/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim#L1

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you.

Comment: it didn't work on the neovim. Would you know how to help me?